# Laravel 5.4 return to login page after auth session expire

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5.4

hi :) i develop some project and i have the same problem in all of them , i cannot handle the method when we did not use the web application for example in 1 hour after refresh the page login page appear instead of error page , please help me how can redirect to login page after the auth timeout., i use this code in beginning of some methods to get user id and when the auth timeout this part of code has error and the error page appear :

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user_id = $user->id;
```

and the error is :

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
```

i want to redirect to login page instead of this error page, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if user is logged in before getting user model:

```
       if(Auth::check()){
           $user = Auth::user();
           $user_id = $user->id;
       }
       else{
           return redirect('login');
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check user logged in or not before using that like

```
if ( Auth::check() ) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user_id = $user->id;
}else{
    return redirect('login');
}
```